# Approach required for automating launching AWS instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have dev environment aws template that has cloudera director installed with all vpc groups , subnet configurations, AMI's S3 bucket etc.

Now I need to establish similar environment ,automate the flow using python boto3 package

I am completely clueless how should I proceed.

Can someone help me from where should I start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to automate launching AWS EC2 instances.

- Creating a AMI with the installed software, and using the AMI and AWS Web Console to provision new servers.
- Creating a CloudFormation Script and having Shell Scripts(Or commandline scripts in Windows) to automate the installation of the software define in "User Data" section. Here you can re-use the CloudFormation storing in S3 for creating new instances.
- Use AWS CLI (Shell commands with scripts) or AWS SDKs (e.g Python boto3 package) to provision the environments. For this you need to create a IAM user (Or Role, if the scripts executes inside an EC2 instance) with required permission to provision the resources.

In addition you can use a combination of these options, to make it easier to maintain. For example, if you plan to setup VPC, Network & etc. for each deployment, its better to keep the infrastructure provisioning in CloudFormation while, may be the setting up of EC2 instance written in Boto3. You can trigger the execution of both CloudFormation and other code in Boto3.

Refer the article [Automating AWS With Python and Boto3](https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/14209-automating-aws-with-python-and-boto3) from LinuxAcademy for step by step guide.

Comment: Ashan,Thanks alot for the information provided.I started to use Cloud Formation Designer . But while writing code in boto3 I am not understanding what code should I write first. Like for ex: Shoud I write code for vpc first ? then write code for launching s3 bucket ec2-instances and all?.I have my project template defined as "vpc-build.template".So should extract the information present in template and build code ?.So many questions arising in my mind bro,Can you please call me for 5 min .My phone number 9791081769.I am very thankful to u if you could help me  in this.One helping hand I need

Comment: I have one more question. If I am using boto3 can I import existing aws template which is in json with some modifications can I deploy the instance s?

Comment: Yes it should be possible. Use the boto3 CloudFormation createStack http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.create_stack

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python package (the official AWS SDK for Python, AKA boto3) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awscli which can be used for automation. AWS CLI is also based on this library.
You can also try https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/ in which you specify json config for the resources to the REST apis provided by AWS.

Comment: Dear Yogi,Can you please spare some 5 min please share your number or please call me to 9791081769 to discuss on this. I won't take much of your time. I am very eager to learn all these. One helping hand I need. You all are experts please help me to bring to ur speed

Comment: By "AWS CLI has a python package" I think you mean, there is a Python package (the official AWS SDK for Python, AKA boto3) which can be used for automation. It just so happens to be the library that the AWS CLI tool is built on.